# Having issues rendering with reactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using , in HTML, a "datalist" which is for dropdown autocomplete. Here is an example

```
<datalist id="languages">
  <option value="HTML">
  <option value="C#">
  <option value="C++">
</datalist>

<input type="text" list="languages">
```

so basically the input text field will give those three options whenever the user is typing.

On my react project I have an empty datalist

```
   <datalist id="allChoices">

    </datalist>

<input id="textField1" list="allChoices" type="text" onkeypress="function1(event)">
```

so as the user types, I will be rendering all the elements to my datalist. However it does not run. Here is the simplified code for function1(the one that activates when user types on the keyboar)

```
function function1(e) {
    ...
    ...

  for (var i=0; i < arrayOptions.length; i++) {
    ReactDOM.render(<option value="{arrayOptions[i]}">,document.getElementById('allChoices'));
  }

}
```

for simplicity, I tried to do this and see if it would work

```
function function1(e) {
    ...
    ...

  for (var i=0; i < arrayOptions.length; i++) {
    ReactDOM.render(<option value="hello">,document.getElementById('allChoices'));
  }

}
```

but still not working/running. I have checked "arrayOptions" and that array is fine. What happens before the for loop works fine.

Is there a syntax error? Or how can I properly render elements from the arrayOptions array into my datalist whenever the user types?

Comment: I suggest stepping back from your current task and working through some React tutorials. In the normal case, you use `ReactDOM.render` **once**, not to render each individual element.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ReactDOM.render` for that. Just return from a functional component to render it